# Need help changing the chromecst image in the actionbar

Tags: android, chromecast

Hi does anyone know how to change the icon when google cast is connected? I want my icon to be blue when it is connected to the chromecast device but mine is showing up white. Also it is the one that is in the action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. One is to replace the icons that the media router library uses in your project. That enables you to change the color for the two states, connected and disconnected. If you want more than that, then you can follow this [article](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2015/03/06/styling-chromecast-icons/) where he goes into details on how to change the theme used there in the library by sub-classing MediaRouteButton from the library. If the first approach is all you need, then do that since it amounts to just replacing a few images. To find out what those images are, look at [media router support library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/marshmallow-release/v7/mediarouter/res/drawable/); in the res/drawables/, you should find XML resources that point to various images that are used and then you use your own version of those images in your own app (keep the names the same).